# Shared desktop solution/api for Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7

I write software for an IT consulting company that supports a number of clients that will (very) soon be migrating from Windows XP to Windows 7.  One of the tools we use is Ultra VNC Single Click, which lets us connect to a client computer and share the user's desktop.  Eventually, I wrote an application that sits on the user's desktop and packages the single click .exe among other tools.  This is extremely useful for the techs, and since it requires both sides to initiate the connection we don't have to leave a service running on the user's workstations that could potentially be exploited, and we can easily access computers without public IPs (most of them).

However, with Windows 7 && UAC, all is not well.  If UAC is active, starting Ultra VNC SC brings up a UAC prompt.  We will not be disabling UAC.  We will not be granting admin rights.  A UAC prompt is a deal ender.

Has anyone else dealt with a similar problem?  Is there a library or program I can use that will allow us to share the users' desktops without forcing a UAC prompt?  I have looked for a way to whitelist my own program, but with no luck.  Maybe a way to temporarily disable UAC entirely?  I am working in .NET, so a .NET solution would be preferred, but I am willing to look elsewhere

Comment: You can't disable UAC without being elevated (i.e. getting a prompt first). This is the whole point of UAC. Could you explain why getting the prompt is a deal ender? User will have to get familiar with this prompt sooner or later anyway unless you are going to disable UAC.

Comment: The prompt is a deal breaker because the end user will not have admin rights.  This is a requirement handed down to me from on high.  The users do not have admin rights, but I need to provide a way for them to share their desktops with us.  I did have another idea though: what if I had a service running in the background that DOES run as admin, and the user front-end could speak to the service

Comment: For regular users there are two types of elevation: One requiring an administrator password giving full permissions, and one requiring only confirmation of the consent dialog by clicking OK, which will let the application run with the highest privileges the current user can obtain. I assume that the latter should be sufficient for your task?

Comment: It would be workable.  We're still left with the problem that UAC prompts do not show up at all on VNC so if the user walks away our tech may end up stuck and SOL...  But that's a whole separate discussion.  For the purpose of starting VNC a simple consent dialog is fine -- provided it doesn't require that the user already be an admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step [tutorial](http://www.vista4beginners.com/Disable-UAC-for-certain-applications) to disable UAC for one application using the [Windows Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en).

Comment: This seems to work pretty well.  Running sdbinst on every workstation would not be workable, but if we can get Active Directory to run it, or else have the installer run it, this might work.  +1, and I'll mark as answer once I'm sure it works